# Multiple sticky columns bootstrap-vue vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have multiple columns that are set as stickyColumn, the columns will stack over each other visually, and the left-most sticky columns may "peek" out from under the next sticky column.

**How to add multiple columns installed without them on top of each other?**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table
      responsive
      :items="items"
      :fields="fields"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fields: [
          { key: 'id', stickyColumn: true, isRowHeader: true, variant: 'primary' },
          { key: 'a', stickyColumn: true, variant: 'info' },
          'b',
          'c',
          'd',
          'e',
          'f',
          'g',
          'h',
          'i',
          'j',
          'k',
          'l'
        ],
        items: [
          { id: 1, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 2, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 3, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 4, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 5, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 6, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 7, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 8, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 9, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 10, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: There is no question, no problem explanation, no expected output.

Comment: @AdamOrlov i add photo, please check it

Answer (score 0):

Sticky columns in b-table are currently stacking by default.

Here is a solution to overriding

```
<template>
  <b-row class="container">
    <b-col cols="12">
      <b-table ref="customTable" striped hover responsive :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage" :items="items" :fields="fields"> </b-table>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { BCol, BRow, BTable } from 'bootstrap-vue'

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    BTable,
    BRow,
    BCol,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      perPage: 5,
      totalRows: 1,
      currentPage: 1,
      fields: [
        {
          key: 'id',
          label: 'Id',
          isRowHeader: true,
          variant: 'primary',
          class: 'sticky-column',
          thStyle: {
            width: '150px',
          },
        },
        {
          key: 'full_name',
          label: 'Full NameFull',
          sortable: true,
          isRowHeader: true,
          variant: 'primary',
          class: 'sticky-column',
          thStyle: {
            width: '150px',
          },
        },
        {
          key: 'post',
          label: 'Post',
          sortable: true,
          isRowHeader: true,
          variant: 'primary',
          class: 'sticky-column',
          thStyle: {
            width: '150px',
          },
        },
        'email',
        'city',
        'start_date',
        'salary',
        'age',
        'experience',
        { key: 'status', label: 'Status', sortable: true },
      ],
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: "Korrie O'Crevy",
          post: 'Nuclear Power Engineer',
          email: 'kocrevy0@thetimes.co.uk',
          city: 'Krasnosilka',
          start_date: '09/23/2016',
          salary: '$23896.35',
          age: '61',
          experience: '1 Year',
          status: 2,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: 'Bailie Coulman',
          post: 'VP Quality Control',
          email: 'bcoulman1@yolasite.com',
          city: 'Hinigaran',
          start_date: '05/20/2018',
          salary: '$13633.69',
          age: '63',
          experience: '3 Years',
          status: 2,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: 'Stella Ganderton',
          post: 'Operator',
          email: 'sganderton2@tuttocitta.it',
          city: 'Golcowa',
          start_date: '03/24/2018',
          salary: '$13076.28',
          age: '66',
          experience: '6 Years',
          status: 5,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: 'Dorolice Crossman',
          post: 'Cost Accountant',
          email: 'dcrossman3@google.co.jp',
          city: 'Paquera',
          start_date: '12/03/2017',
          salary: '$12336.17',
          age: '22',
          experience: '2 Years',
          status: 2,
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: 'Harmonia Nisius',
          post: 'Senior Cost Accountant',
          email: 'hnisius4@gnu.org',
          city: 'Lucan',
          start_date: '08/25/2017',
          salary: '$10909.52',
          age: '33',
          experience: '3 Years',
          status: 2,
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: 'Genevra Honeywood',
          post: 'Geologist',
          email: 'ghoneywood5@narod.ru',
          city: 'Maofan',
          start_date: '06/01/2017',
          salary: '$17803.80',
          age: '61',
          experience: '1 Year',
          status: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: 'Eileen Diehn',
          post: 'Environmental Specialist',
          email: 'ediehn6@163.com',
          city: 'Lampuyang',
          start_date: '10/15/2017',
          salary: '$18991.67',
          age: '59',
          experience: '9 Years',
          status: 3,
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: 'Richardo Aldren',
          post: 'Senior Sales Associate',
          email: 'raldren7@mtv.com',
          city: 'Skoghall',
          start_date: '11/05/2016',
          salary: '$19230.13',
          age: '55',
          experience: '5 Years',
          status: 3,
        },
        {
          id: 9,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: 'Allyson Moakler',
          post: 'Safety Technician',
          email: 'amoakler8@shareasale.com',
          city: 'Mogilany',
          start_date: '12/29/2018',
          salary: '$11677.32',
          age: '39',
          experience: '9 Years',
          status: 5,
        },
        {
          id: 10,
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          full_name: 'Merline Penhalewick',
          post: 'Junior Executive',
          email: 'mpenhalewick9@php.net',
          city: 'Kanuma',
          start_date: '04/19/2019',
          salary: '$15939.52',
          age: '23',
          experience: '3 Years',
          status: 2,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  mounted() {
    this.totalRows = this.items.length
    const tableEl = this.$refs.customTable.$el
    const offsetLeft = tableEl.getBoundingClientRect().left
    const stickColEl = document.querySelectorAll('.sticky-column')
    stickColEl.forEach((el) => {
      const { x } = el.getBoundingClientRect()
      el.style.left = `${x - offsetLeft}px`
    })
  },
  methods: {},
})
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sticky-column {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
</style>
```